# White Blanks to the Right in Mobile View of Website

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, zurb-foundation

I'm debugging a website for a code written by somebody else. Typically I used bootstrap for responsive rows and columns but I believe this site is built on zurb-foundation.

Here is the url of the page. (www.edcast.com/privacy)

screenshot for a a visual of what i mean.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/4TdN0.jpg

I will play around with this, but having a second eye and some other input would be highly appreciated!

Update: So far I've tried changing "overflow: visible" to hidden and auto
        I've also tried to apply a clear: both to a variety of different divs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you take a look at the image I posted below, you can see that the div with the id `image-top-div` is pushing everything over. You will need to resize the image and play with the margin and padding. You can see me here in the gif taking out the `margin-left` which solves it. [image]

[image: Website screenshot]

Comment: a picture of what happens when I typed the code above in console.

http://imgur.com/Ko7hl2b


it just seems to say "undefined"


    I did however find out the problem starts at 450px width or smaller

Comment: @tonesbonesjones That just means there were no elements that were wider than the page. There was padding on one of your `div`s that was pushing everything over, I updated my answer to reflect that.

Comment: I tried testing with padding-right: 0px in the browser.

It didn't seem to work, but I appreciate you trying to help me on this. :)

http://i.imgur.com/N7M948t.png

Comment: I also found this archived on stackoverflow [Archived Solution](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5804441/website-body-background-rendering-a-right-white-margin-in-iphone-safari) I'm currently testing each one of the methods mentioned @773