# Extra spacing outside the viewable area

Tags: css, html, wordpress

I have a very strange bug that involves extra spacing on the body or html element. This spacing does not appear in a normal browser's viewable area, it's only seen if you do a mouse scroll to the right side of the screen.

Please take a look at the staging site I've setup to see exactly what I mean. http://silo.radishlab.com

I'm going to assume this is some css bug I've created for myself, but I haven't been able to track down the source.

Comment: Maybe this could help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4617872/white-space-showing-up-on-right-side-of-page-when-background-image-should-extend

Comment: @Tip_Top a fiddle is not needed, nor helpful being that he has linked his entire site where the problem exists.

Comment: @Tip_Top I see the merit in that, but creating a fiddle for this problem isn't feasible, being that it "was" unknown where the problem exists. Just my opinion.

Answer (score 1):

In your styles you have 40px worth of left and right padding on `.footer-container footer` which pushes it out beyond the 100% limit.

You can get around this by using something like `box-sizing: border-box;` (which requires vendor prefixing)

Or by removing the padding and using different methods to get that space without pushing out the container width.

Comment: That's part of the issue, the other part is the next arrow on the slider. The extra space was being created when not hovering the slider and the arrow was pushed to the right. After removing the "right:-50px" from ".flex-direction-nav .flex-next" the problem went away.

Comment: Ah, my mistake, I had disabled the arrow first and saw no change so when I disabled the padding on the footer I forgot about the arrow. Thanks for pointing it out!

Answer (score 1):

You have 2 culprits.

1. Your `<footer id="colophon">` has `width: 100%` and left padding of `61px`. Remove the left padding and instead put that padding in the parent element `<div class="footer-container">`.
2. Set `<article id="slider">` to have `overflow:hidden`.

Comment: Or instead of changing the padding, "overflow:hidden" could be added to "footer-container"