# How to remove whitespace in ipad?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, ipad, responsive-design, whitespace

I am using bootstrap responsive design, when viewing my webpage in iPad it results in empty whitespace at right side, i set width as device-width in viewport meta tag, how to remove empty whitespace?

I tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4617872/white-space-showing-up-on-right-side-of-page-when-background-image-should-extend), nothing works correctly

Comment: Any chance you could share code? Or a link?

Comment: seems to be generic ipad issue

Comment: If you mean a big whitespace extending your page way beyond your viewport, I've seen that happen before too. Every time that happened, there was some element css which didn't behave properly. Often a combination including `width: 100%`, but I forgot the exact problem. I can help you if you have a link, or a dummy page (jsfiddle) so we can find what causes it. CSS solved it for me in the past.

Comment: needless to say , can't fix design related problem without looking at design

Answer (score 0):

White-space is a text char. Just make text invisible using `font: 0/0 a;`.
Let me explain. Two examples with common HTML:

```
<div>
<!--White-space -->
<span>Some text here<span>
</div>
```

Example 1. With white-space on iPad([`jsfiddle`](http://jsfiddle.net/He5LZ/show)) with css:

```
div {
    background: red;
}

span {
    background: blue;
    color: #fff;
}
```

Example 2. Without white-space on iPad([`jsfiddle`](http://jsfiddle.net/He5LZ/2/show)) with css:

CSS:

```
div {
    background: red;
    font: 0/0 a;/*make text invisible for parent container with white-spaces*/
}

span {
    background: blue;
    color: #fff;
    font: 12px/normal Arial, sans-serif;/*set back font for child container*/
    display:inline-block;/*just for good render effect*/
}
```

Comment: I have a doubt where to add this code, I have multiple pages/div/span in my website, should i add font:0/0 a; on bootstrap navbar

Comment: Add `font:0/0 a;` to top parent node where you have a problem