# Entire website has white margin on its right side in Mobile view

Tags: html, css, web

[image]

I have tried to

1. set body and html width to 100% !important
2. checked the viewport which has the correct value

   > width=device-width,initial-scale=1,shrink-to-fit=no

so I run out of ideas about what's next to check.

Could someone enlighten me please.

**update**
My question is marked as duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4617872/white-space-showing-up-on-right-side-of-page-when-background-image-should-extend) and ask me to explain it, okay here we go:

[image]

As you can see that if I added this code

```
html,body
{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    overflow-x: hidden; 
}
```

I will have a huge white gap between hero image and my next section, and the Top Notch section gone missing.

Comment: Can you share a link?

Comment: @Utkanos sure, thanks.  http://vibeshtml.dharansh.in/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [White space showing up on right side of page when background image should extend full length of page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4617872/white-space-showing-up-on-right-side-of-page-when-background-image-should-extend)

Comment: hi @KamaleshM.Talaviya please see my update

Comment: before i add that code : https://ibb.co/1KXYQSJ

Comment: after added that code : https://ibb.co/FVnBNcy

Comment: full page : https://ibb.co/gjSvfXz

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your viewport is scaled when you resize browser window, so adding user-scalable=0 will solve that problem. (at present when you press ctrl+0 it solves the issue)

Replace your viewport with this:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, height=device-height, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=0">
```

Comment: It solves the problem!  thanks ~!  Now could you please explain why adding : height=device-height, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=0  makes it work??? thanks!

Comment: your current meta does not include `user-scalable=0` so when you resize browser window it does not scale properly because it is unable to properly detect the device. meta viewport tags are to detect the device and render page accordingly

Comment: in more detail you can refer [here](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/html/responsive-meta-tag/) It would be helpful if you accept the answer. Thanks !

Comment: for sure! This is the 1st solution :) thanks a lot~!

Comment: hi Joy, "user-scalable: Allows the device to zoom in and out. Values are yes or no." It doesn't mention anything about detect the device.  Could you please explain why it works in the way you mentioned before???

Comment: "A <meta> viewport element gives the browser instructions on how to control the page's dimensions and scaling." from [w3school](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_meta.asp) my explanation of detecting device was about meta tag not specifically `user-scalable` and I tried to explain it in a easy way, but not official terms.

Comment: appreicated :) I will note it down

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your browser view port issue. When we change port without refresh it looks like you have shared but when we open in the same port it works fine. Also i have tested in online simulator working fine. Check this
http://www.responsinator.com/?url=vibeshtml.dharansh.in%2F

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I have noticed in your you are using "row" class and then in "col-*" classes you are making "p-0". The ideal way to achieve is if you dont want gutter space, then apply "row no-gutters" with "row" class and remove "p-0" from all col classes.
At times, this problem also causes issues of space across different views.