# CSS padding to the right when window is resized smaller

Tags: css, whitespace

I have padding to the right of my archives and search page and I believe it has to do with my body element, however I'm not quite sure what is different on these pages are from the other pages on the site of which are all fine for style wise as they all use the same format. [It's a wordpress website.](http://www.averylawoffice.ca/2012/04) As I said, it's only happening to this page and the search page and all others are fine, so I'm confused as to what it's doing.

```
html { font-size: 100%; overflow-y: scroll; -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%; -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%; background: url(img/BG.jpg) repeat; min-width:1024px; }

body { margin: 0px; padding 0px; font-size: 13px; line-height: 1.231; background: url(img/NAV-bg.jpg) top repeat-x;}

header { width: 960px; height: auto; margin: 0 auto; display: block;}

#container { width: 960px; margin: 20px auto; padding: 0 1.5em;}

aside { width: 260px; height: auto; float: left; position: relative;}

#main { width: 650px; height: auto; float: right; position: relative;}

#footer { width: 100%; min-width:1024px; display: block; height: 503px; background: url(img/FOOTER-bg.jpg) repeat-x; background-color: #821d20; position: relative; top: 100px; }
```

If you decrease the size of your window you'll notice that a scroll bar on the bottom of the page shows up and then the padding on the right starts to take shape. If you make your window larger that padding space is then gone and the scroll bar on the bottom disappears. Have I restricted my body tag in any way to have this happen?

I've looked through this one but I already have a min-width defined.
[Website has strange whitespace on right side of the page when the browser is resized to a smaller window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4612307/website-has-strange-whitespace-on-right-side-of-the-page-when-the-browser-is-res)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your `style.css` file at Line 108, remove the `width` attribute from the header tag to fix your horizontal scrollbar issue.

**Fixed CSS:**

```
header { height: auto; margin: 0 auto; display: block;}
```

For review, [**3D View in Firefox**](http://blog.mozilla.org/blog/2012/03/13/firefox-adds-new-developer-tools-and-add-on-sync/) browser shows the header as the gray bar with is the root of your problem. The other styles that create the text are not affected.
[image]

**Tip:** Right mouse-click the above image and view in new tab to see in original size.

Answer (score 0):

Ah, if I'm understanding your problem correctly, it appears that the tag `header`, specifically its style `width: 960px`, is what is causing this peculiar occurrence. The containing div around the header, `#main`, only has `width: 650px`. As a result, the excess width of the header causes it to extend beyond the edge of the div.

The reason why it seems to be appearing as padding only at smaller screen widths is because the containing div around all that, `#container`, is centered by its margins - so the effects of the over-wide header won't become apparent until the browser is thin enough such that its right edge begins to overlap the right side of the header.

Rather than fixing this by just dropping the `width: 960px` from the styles of the header (which may mess up the site where this width for header tags is actually needed), I would suggest adding an overriding class to all offending tags, perhaps on the lines of `.archive-header { width: auto; }`. But I guess the solution is up to you, since you probably know the site better than I do.

I hope this helps! (I really do, otherwise you'd have read all this for nothing! Sorry if you did...) For the future, try downloading [Firebug for Mozilla Firefox](http://getfirebug.com/), which has a handy element inspector which will let you play around with the styles of elements to see what works. It should help you spot these kinds of issues on your own, so you can fix them quicker.